# Prolog operators table meaning

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to find a table of prolog operators explained. I found this:
http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators

But they are not explained. I'm looking more specifically for the meaning of:

```
\==, >>, <<
```

Subsidiary question:

I understand that \== is not evaluating the both term of the expression.

What would be the operators for having both term evaluated ? (similar to != in other languages..)

Comment: [`(\==)/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dterm_005fnot_005fequal_005fto.html#mpg_002dref_002dterm_005fnot_005fequal_005fto), and [arithmetic expressions](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dari.html#ref_002dari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog operators are just syntactic sugar for ordinary prolog terms. The infix operator `\==` is the built-in predicate `\==/2`. See http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compare for details.

The infix operators `<<` and `>>` are the built-in arithimetic functions `<</2` and `>>/2` respectively. See http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=functions for details.

As far as a comparison operator that evaluated both the left- and right-hand sides as arithmetic expressions, you want `=:=/2` and its converse `=\=/2`, which see documented at http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arith